# position sticky

Tags: html, jquery, css, position

Проблема в position stickyю Если я его добавляю, то скрипт работает только 1 раз: отматывая вниз, вверх после этого не отматывает.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[href*='#']").on("click", function(e) {
    var anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 777);
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
/* SASS
                CSS №1
            body
                max-width: 100%  
            *
                cursor: default 
                margin: 0
                padding: 0
                font-family: 'Open Sans', sans
                
                text-decoration: none 
                
            
            .in_header
                position: fixed
                width: 270px
                height: 100%
                background: linear-gradient(to top, #007ad8, #0984e3)
                display: flex 
                justify-content: center  
                align-items: center  
                flex-direction: column 
              
                img
                    height: 200px
                    border-radius: 50%
                    border: solid 8px #74b9ff
                ul 
                    margin: 0  
                    padding: 0  
                    li 
                        list-style: none
                        font-size: 20px
                        font-weight: bold
                        text-align: center
                        margin: 20px 0
                        a 
                            color: #bfdfff
                            position: relative
                            padding: 5px
                            display: block
                            transition: all 0.5s ease
                            text-transform: uppercase
                ul:hover li a 
                    transform: scale(1.2)
                    transition: all 0.5s ease
                    opacity: .2
                    filter: blur(5px)
                    color: white
                ul li a:hover 
                    transform: scale(1.6)
                    transition: all 0.5s ease
                    opacity: 1
                    filter: blur(0)
                ul li a:before
                    content: ''
                    position: absolute
                    left: 0 
                    top: 0
                    width: 100%
                    height: 100%
            
            section
                position: sticky
                top: 0
                margin-left: 270px
                height: 100%
                background: white
            section:before 
                content: ''
                width: 100%
                height: 100%
                z-index: -1
                box-shadow:  0 -50px 50px 50px #636e72
            .content 
                margin: 0 5vw
                max-width: 80%
                height: 100vh
                border-top: 2px solid #dfe6e9
                align-items: center
                display: flex
            .info 
                font-size: 20px
                color: #818181
            h1 
                color: #0984e3
                font-size: 60px
                font-weight: bolder
                .h1_color
                    color: #636e72
            #s1
                ul 
                    display: flex
                    li
                        list-style: none
                        .mail 
                            color: #0984e3
                            font-size: 20px
                            margin-left: 10px
                        .tel 
                            color: #636e72
                            font-size: 20px
                div
                    display: flex
                    flex-direction: column
                    .vk_link
                        width: 70px
                        height: 70px
                        a 
                            width: 40px
                            height: 40px
                            border-radius: 50%
                            padding: 5px
                            margin: 10px 0
                            position: relative
                            overflow: hidden
                            border: 2px solid #636e72
                            color: #636e72
                            display: flex
                            justify-content: center
                            align-items: center
                            
                            font-size: 35px
                            transition: all 0.5s ease
                        a:hover 
                            color: white
                            box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0984e3
                            border: none
                            transform: scale(1.2)
            .vk_link
                a:before
                    content: ''
                    position: absolute
                    top: 0
                    left: 0
                    width: 0
                    height: 100%
                    background: #0984e3
                    z-index: -1
                    transition: all 0.5s ease
                a:hover::before
                    width: 100%
                    transition: all 0.5s ease
            #s2 
                i
                    font-size: 50px
                    color: #636e72
                    margin-right: 20px
            h2 
                color: #636e72
                margin: 20px 0         
            #s3
                div 
                    div
                        width: 50px
                        height: 50px
                        background: #636e72
                        display: flex
                        justify-content: center  
                        align-items: center 
                        border-radius: 50%
                        margin-top: 20px
                        transition: all 0.5s ease
                        a
                            display: flex
                            justify-content: center  
                            align-items: center 
                            i
                                font-size: 45px
                                color: white
                                margin: 3px 9px 0 0
                    div:hover
                        background: linear-gradient(to top, #0e80b2, #0e1a30)
                        box-shadow:  0 -50px 50px 50px #636e72
                        transform: scale(1.2)    
                        transition: all 0.5s ease    
            #s4
                display: flex
                flex-direction: column
                .error
                    color:  #0984e3
                    font-size: 30vw
                    font-weight: bold
                
                
                
                
                
            @media screen and (max-width: 768px)
                nav ul li 
                    display: none
            
                .all_margin_left
                     margin: 0
                .in_header
                    position: static
            
            CSS №2
            .hidden-menu a {
              color: rgb(134, 182, 255);
              text-decoration: none !important;
            }
            .hidden-menu a:hover {
              color: white;
              transition: all 0.3s;
            }
            .hidden-menu {
              text-align: center;
              font-size: 20px;
              font-weight: bold;
              display: block;
              position: fixed;
              list-style: none;
              padding: 10px;
              margin: 0;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              width: 270px;
              background: linear-gradient(to top, #1155bb, #1975ff);
              height: 100%;
              top: 0;
              left: -270px;
              transition: left 0.2s;
              z-index: 2;
              -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
              -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            }
            .hidden-menu-ticker {
              display: none;
            }
            .btn-menu {
              border-radius: 2px;
              background-color: #4992ff;
              padding: 5px;
              position: fixed;
              top: 5px;
              left: 5px;
              transition: left 0.23s;
              z-index: 3;
              width: 30px;
              -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
              -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            }
            .btn-menu span {
              display: block;
              height: 3px;
              background-color: #b8d4ff;
              margin: 7px 0 0;
              transition: all 0.1s linear 0.23s;
              position: relative;
            }
            .btn-menu span.first {
              margin-top: 0;
            }
            .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu {
              left: 230px;
            }
            .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .hidden-menu {
              left: 0;
            }
            .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.first {
              -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
              top: 10px;
            }
            .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.second {
              opacity: 0;
            }
            .hidden-menu-ticker:checked ~ .btn-menu span.third {
              -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
              top: -10px;
            }
            @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
              .btn-menu {
                display: none;
              }
              
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
              nav ul li {
                display: none;
              }
              .all_margin_left {
                margin: 0 !important;
              }
              .in_header{
                height: auto !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                position: inherit;
                color: rgb(116, 116, 116)
              }
              header div img {
                margin: 10px;
              }
            }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="in_header ">
    <img src="app/img/f1.jpg" alt="" />
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#s1">О себе</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s2">Что я умею</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s3">Интересы</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s4">Опыт</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s5">Информация</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<section>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hmt" class="hidden-menu-ticker" />
  <label class="btn-menu" for="hmt">
                            <span class="first"></span>
                            <span class="second"></span>
                            <span class="third"></span>
                          </label>
  <ul class="hidden-menu">
    <li><a href="#s1">О себе</a></li>
    <li><a href="#s2">Что я умею</a></li>
    <li><a href="#s3">Интересы</a></li>
    <li><a href="#s4">Опыт</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#s4">Информация</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="content  section_first" id="s1">
    <div>
      <h1><span class="h1_color">Bulat</span> Mustafin</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="tel:+79631322869" class="tel">+7 (963) 132-28-69</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="mailto:damask161092@gmail.com" class="mail">damask161092@gmail.com</a
                                  >
                                </li>
                              </ul>
                              <p class="info">Hачинающий веб разработчик.</p>
                              <div class="vk_link">
                                <a href="https://vk.com/im?peers=204230450_202106715_104516837&sel=101730206" target="_blank" >
                                  <i class="fab fa-vk"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="content" id="s2">
    <div>
      <h2>Что я умею</h2>
      <p class="info">
        На данный момент я владею html , CSS, практиковал Sass. Немного изучал Java синтаксис которого схож с PHP, JavaScript это позволяет мне немного понимать написанное на этих языках и делать небольшие исправления. Также на уровне любителя я владею photoshop
        и illustrator
      </p>
      <br />
      <i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
      <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i>
      <i class="fab fa-sass"></i>
      <i class="fab fa-adobe"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="content" id="s3">
    <div>
      <h2>Интересы</h2>
      <p class="info">Интересы у меня вполне обычные, это Видео игры</p>
      <div>
        <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198866394726" target="_blank"><br>
          <i class="fab fa-steam-symbol"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="content" id="s4">
    <p class="error">404</p>
    <p class="info">Информация не найдена зайдите по позже</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="content " id="s5">
    <p class="info">Сайт написан на Visual Studio Code. При написаний использован препроцессор Sass, скомпилироанный с помощью таск менеджера gulp, с помощью него же уменьшен вес. Верстка посажена на WordPress</p>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Если вы его добавляете какому элементу?

Comment: к селектору section Внутри которых распологаеться весь контент кроме саидбара

Comment: Вы хотите проскролить к элементу, который зафиксирован `sticky` ?

Comment: Нет идея в том как скролятся основные блоки (section) по нажатии на ссылку на якорь они должны как бы накрывать один другого. При скролинге вниз все срабатывает как надо но когда нажимаешь на якорь который располагается выше наверх вообще не крутятся. Такое происходит из за добавления position sticky top 0. Идет какой то конфликт между этими значениями в css и jquery скриптом который я добовляю